# Convert only float in the mixed type list

Tags: python, list, typechecking

I have the following list:

```
ls1 = ['xxx', 3.88884, 2.383, 1.999, '-']
```

what I want to do is to convert the float value into `"%.2f"`, resulting this:

```
['xxx', '3.88', '2.38', '1.99', '-']
```

But why this code failed?

```
def stringify_result_list(reslist):
    finals = []
    print reslist
    for res in reslist:
        if type(res) == 'float':
           tmp = "%.2f" % res
           finals.append(tmp)
        else:
           finals.append(res)
    print finals
    return finals

 stringify_result_list(ls1)
```

Comment: `type` doesn't return a string. For e.g `>>> type(type(10))
<type 'type'>`

Comment: And you almost never want to check `type(res)` anyway; use `isinstance`. If someone gave you an instance of a subclass of `float` (like, e.g., NumPy's `float64`, which looks exactly like a `float` in almost every way), would you want that to be converted to string, or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`type(res)` does not return what you think it does:

```
>>> type(1.0)
<type 'float'>
>>> type(type(1.0))
<type 'type'>
>>>
```

As you can see, it returns the type object for floats, not the string `"float"`.  You can read about this behavior in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type):

> `class type(object)`
>   
>   `class type(name, bases, dict)`
>
> With one argument, return the type of an object. **The return value is a type object.** The `isinstance()` built-in function is recommended
>   for testing the type of an object.

---

That said, you can greatly simplify your function by using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
def stringify_result_list(reslist):
    return ["%.2f" % x if isinstance(x, float) else x for x in reslist]
```

You'll notice too that I used [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance) to test whether each item is a float.  As the quote above says, this is the preferred method of typechecking in Python.